# Error checking - shellscript

Tags: bash

I'm new to shell scripting and i'm writing this script to create file with permissions and checking if file exist or not. Everything is working fine but when I don't specify argument it says missing argument but still gives me no such file or directory error which i'm not getting. Can someone help ?

Code:

```
#!/bin/bash`enter code here`
# checking the argument
if [[ ! $1 ]]; then
    echo "missing argument, please check !"
fi

# variable holding the script name.
scriptname="$1"

# creates shellscript and changes the permissions of script to u+x.
# Adds #!/bin/bash line to script.
if [[ ! -e "${scriptname}" ]]; then
    echo "#!/bin/bash" >> "${scriptname}" && chmod u+x "${scriptname}"
else
    echo "file " ${scriptname} " exists, create a new file."
fi
```

Comment: After `echo "missing argument, please check !"` you probably want to add an `exit 1` statement (on the next line)

Comment: @janos thanks for the correction and it's working fine now.

Answer (score 0):

The underlying problem here is that you're not exiting the program after a condition is satisfied as pointer by  [@janos](https://stackoverflow.com/users/641955/janos)  [[ **here** ]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44872808/error-checking-shellscript#comment76724096_44872808). So the solution to your problem is

```
if [[ ! $1 ]]; then
    echo "missing argument, please check !"
    exit 1 # A non zero exit status implies an error in Linux
fi
```

However, a neater way to do the same is to use [[ param expansion ]](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html)

```
if [ ${1:-no_file_entered} = "no_file_entered" ]]; then
    echo "missing argument, please check !"
    exit 1 # A non zero exit status implies an error in Linux
fi
```